# Orders where credit card payments fail are not showing up in orders list

Tags: orders, sales

My question is, if a credit card payment fails with Authorize.net (for instance)... does it not show in the dashboard under Sales > Orders because it failed? In other words, does the orders section only show orders that were authorized and/or captured successfully?

With my old cart, the orders list would show all orders including orders that failed. I could then access the order in the dashboard and see why it failed (address bad, zip bad, etc).

I noticed today that my admin only shows orders that are good.
I would like to see failed attempts, to possibly safe sales.

Unless Magento puts these details somewhere else?

Comment: We also have xcart platforms. Even little xcart has a save failed cart feature and much more. Wish they made x cart so you could have multi sites.

Answer (score 3):

Magento considers the shopping cart to be a quote.

It doesn't get converted to being a **Sales Order** until the order is completed and the **Success** page is viewed, therefore you will never see declined credit card payments in the`Sales=>Order` grid as no **Sales Order** ever is created.

The usual method is to have Magento email the declined orders to you.

This is set up under `System=>Configuration=>Checkout=>Payment Failed Emails`

Answer (score 1):

Create an observer and dispatch an event to capture failed things in a seperate log.  That should take care of this stuffs for you :3